# Can I create multiple e-mail channels in If This Then That?

Tags: if-this-then-that

I've just been sent a link to [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com/wtf) and it looks like it might be very useful.

You have various "channels" for the "this" and "that" actions, one of them being e-mail. So you can set up a recipe that states:

> If it's going to rain tomorrow send me an e-mail.

Now I have various e-mail accounts and addresses so what I'd like is to set up multiple e-mail channels.

Is this possible?

Comment: What you mean is that you want to send it to multiple addresses?

Comment: @arieljannai - no. If I remember correctly I wanted to set up different rules to go to different e-mail addresses for filtering purposes.

Comment: Oh, OK - so you wanted to connect multiple email accounts to work with them

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's a channel for GMail that you can setup in addition to using the email address associated with your account.

You could probably send the notification to a GMail account and use that to do some filtering and routing of the messages for you.

Comment: What if I don't have a GMail account ;) Actually, I've seen that the GMail channel isn't available for all recipes so this might not be the universal solution.

Comment: I thought they were mandatory now.  Hehe.  Ah, I didn't actually road test that one yet, so fair enough.  That is frustrating that you can't send more emails!

Answer (score 2):

With GMail action you can choose any to: field, that is, send e-mail to anybody (so you might consider creating GMail account just for IFTTT).

Unfortunately there is no way to register multiple e-mail channels to receive mail from multiple e-mail addresses, but you can use labels (or search) in GMail or tags in mail trigger to trigger different actions. You might be able to "cheat" by registering one GMail address + another e-mail address and then receive triggers from another e-mail address, but I haven't tried that.

So basically, you need GMail to send e-mail to others, and you can't trigger by e-mail from more than one (or maybe two) e-mail accounts.